# Integrating $\int \frac{x^2+1}{x(x^2-1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I integrate the following.

$$\int \frac{x^2+1}{x(x^2-1)}$$

I have done the following.

$$\frac{x^2}{(x)(x+1)(x-1)}$$

$$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x+1}+\frac{C}{x-1}$$

I then did $\quad \displaystyle A(x^2-1)+B(x-1)+C(x+1)=x^2+1$

Then $\quad Ax^2-1A+Bx-1B+Cx+C=x^2+1$

Grouping I get  $$Ax^2=x^2,\quad A=1, \quad C=1,\quad Bx+Cx=0, \quad B=-1$$

Then plug back in

$$\int\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x-1}$$

But I am not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: You get $A(x^2-1) + Bx(x-1) + Cx(x+1) = x^2+1$. You missed a factor $x$ for $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Oh I see how foolish

Comment: So would my system be like dis $Ax^2-1a+bx^2-bx+cx^2+cx=x^2+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2}{(x)(x+1)(x-1)} = \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x+1}+\frac{C}{x-1}$$

$$A(x^ - 1) + Bx(x-1) + Cx(x+ 1) = (A + B + C)x^2 + (-B+ C)x + -A = x^2 + 1$$
$$A + B + C = 1$$
$$C - B = 0\iff B = C$$
$$-A = 1\iff A = -1$$

Now, we have $$A = -1,\;B = C, \implies A + B + C = -1 + 2B = 1 \iff 2B = 2 \iff B = C = 1$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I think I can take it from there...

Comment: Yes I see for A=-1 C=1 and B=1

Comment: Nice work, that's what I get too!

Comment: There seems to be another to solve it in that you can plug in x=-1, x=0 and x=1 and solve the system

Comment: Can you now integrate? Use $\ln(f(x))$ for each denominator $f(x)$

Comment: Yes, that way is quick and dirty, and works well, though in this case, the answers fall out quite nicely without using that trick.

Comment: Yes I get for my final answer -ln(x)+ln(x+1)+ln(x-1)+c

Comment: Very nice, Fernando!

Comment: I see thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that we can use the laws of logarithms to write this as $$-\ln(x)+\ln(x+1)+\ln(x-1)+C = \ln((x + 1)(x-1)) - \ln x + C= \ln (x^2 - 1) - \ln x + C = \ln\left(\dfrac{x^2 - 1}{x}\right)+ C$$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you have $$\int\frac{x^2+1}{x(x^2-1)}dx=\int\frac{x^2}{x(x^2-1)}dx+\int\frac{1}{x(x^2-1)}dx$$ $$=\int\frac{x}{(x^2-1)}dx+\int\frac{1}{x(x^2-1)}dx=\int\frac{x}{(x^2-1)}dx+\int\left(\frac{1/2}{x+1}+\frac{1/2}{x-1}-\frac{1}x\right)dx$$ $$=\int\frac{du}{2u}+\int\left(\frac{1/2}{x+1}+\frac{1/2}{x-1}-\frac{1}x\right)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x(x^2-1)} = \frac{(x+1)^2-2x}{x(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{x+1}{x(x-1)} - \frac{2}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x(x-1)} - \frac{(x+1)-(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x}  + \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x}  + \frac{1}{x+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to note that you can calculate

$$\int \frac{x^2-1}{x(x^2-1)} \mbox{and} \int \frac{3x^2-1}{x(x^2-1)}$$

Now

$$x^2+1=(3x^2-1)-2(x^2-1)$$

Thus, your integral is

$$\int \frac{3x^2-1}{x^3-x}- 2\int \frac{x^2-1}{x(x^2-1)}$$